# FaceTime Failed: Person Not Available

Tags: ipad, facetime

Consider an iPad 2 using WiFi attepting to make FaceTime calls to users on an iPhone 4. Each contact has their phone number defined under the iPhone tag (as opposed to Mobile).

Whenever attempting a FaceTime connection, FaceTime attempts to connect, and fails with the error:

> FaceTime failed - 'Person' is not available for FaceTime.

Measures attempted:

- close FaceTime from running apps.
- disable & re-enable FaceTime from Settings.
- confirmed the device's WiFi is active & enabled.

I've seen the 'solution' of "reset all settings", but suspect that's overkill, and likely won't work, as reported by lots of other users.

How can this error be avoided?

Comment: Are you saying that the iPhone user has everything configured appropriately, but Facetime calls do not reach them?

Comment: Did you ever try the opposite way? have them call you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[According to Apple](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4246), some of the symptoms are:**

- When you are calling someone on FaceTime, the number on their screen
  is not your number.
- People are unable to initiate a FaceTime call
  with you.
- After installing a new carrier settings update, FaceTime
  does not activate.

**How to fix:**

- In Settings > Phone, turn FaceTime OFF and turn it back ON again
- Go to Settings > General > Reset > Reset all settings
- Done

Comment: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4246

Answer (score 1):

Also be sure that BOTH devices are on wifi, not just the iPad.